# mysql insert record without using 'values'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO class

(name, description, personid)

Select name, description, 12 from Class where PersonID = 3;

Select * from Class

Select * from Person
```

Why is the values words is missing from above statement? I thought it should be like this `insert into tableA('name') values('select name from tableB')` ?

Comment: Thats the sytax for inserting something while selecting some data from a table, you cant do much about it so as we.

Comment: This isn't a real question to solve an issue. It is a theory question. Anyway, it is because, when you use the select statement in a insert, "values" is useless.

Comment: Have you read any documentation on INSERT syntax?  There are answers to this question all over the Web.

Comment: That's just the way it is

Comment: it's called [INSERT STATEMENT USING SUB-SELECT](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/insert.php)

Answer (score 1):

Insert data one Table to another table 
OR 
Not Using Value keyword

Insert into Table2 (Name , Address , Mobile) Select Column 1, Column 2  , Column 3 From Table1

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different techniques of INSERT, the code above is inserting values from the table itself and change only the `personid` to 12, he use select so that he can copy the data aside from hardcoded `personid` . that's why you didn't see the `VALUES` keyword , but that's true.. the basic insert statement we learn from school is `INSERT INTO TableName (Col1, Col2... etc) VALUES (Value1, Value2... etc)` , INSERTION of data depends on the requirements that you are working on.